# lightSlider multiple controls visible

Tags: jquery, html

I have integrated the lightSlider jQuery plug in into my site but im getting a funky output. I have embedded the slider in a Bootstrap panel to list images.(Nevermind the mind the blade syntax). Below I have circled the issue that is popping up on my screen when the html is rendered.[image: Red Circles illustrate my issue]

HTML

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="curations">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Work</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        @if(is_null($user->posts))
        No work has been uploaded yet.
        @else
        <ul id="light-slider">
            @foreach ($user->posts as $post)
                @if($post->media_type=='image')
                <li data-thumb="{{$post->media_url}}"> 
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive"src="{{$post->media_url}}">
                    </a>
                </li>
                @endif
            @endforeach    
        </ul>
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: you'd better to create an example in CODEPEN or JSFIDDLE generating the error that you see in your website. Otherwise, it is not possible to diagnose and resolve errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when rendering multiple sliders on the same page. I had to generate a unique "ID" attribute for 
 `<ul id="light-slider">`

Then call each slider individually.

Something like:

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="curations">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Work</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        @if(is_null($user->posts))
        No work has been uploaded yet.
        @else
        <ul id="{{$uniqueSliderID}}">
            @foreach ($user->posts as $post)
                @if($post->media_type=='image')
                <li data-thumb="{{$post->media_url}}"> 
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive"src="{{$post->media_url}}">
                    </a>
                </li>
                @endif
            @endforeach    
        </ul>

        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {
               $("{{$uniqueSliderID}}").lightSlider(); 
             });
        </script>
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>
<div>
```